# How do I automatically make changes to browser settings using HTML?

Tags: python, html, url, browser, auto

Have a nice day. I need to create a link using HTML. When I open this link in the browser, I want my browser to automatically change the browser language in its settings.
So I can use HTML, PY, or any other programming language to automatically enable or disable any settings in the browser settings using HTML?

How can I use HTML or Python for this?

Comment: I do not think this is possible.  I certainly wouldn't want some random website to be able to change my browser's language setting...

Comment: It is (fortunately) not possible. You can only read client-side settings but not set. I don't even see the use-case for what you are asking.